# BCP command not working with global temp table in SQL Server 2016 but works in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, bcp

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempTrans') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TempTrans;

SET @XMLFile = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CAST(@XMLDocument AS VARCHAR(MAX));

SELECT REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @XMLFile), 'xmlns=""','') AS x INTO ##TempTrans;

SET @SQLFile = 'bcp "SELECT x FROM ##TempTrans" queryout "'+ @FilePath + '" -c -T'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQLFile
```

While using above query in SQL Server 2016 instance I am getting error which states:
**Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '##TempTrans'.
**

While same query is working without any error in SQL Server 2019 instance.

What can be the possible solution of this issue?

Comment: Is your SQL 2016 instance the default instance? If not, append `'-S ' + @@SERVERNAME` to the @SQLFile value.

Comment: You were right! SQL 2016 instance was not my default Instance. I have to append Server Information in the query.
Its working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @SQLFile = 'bcp "SELECT x FROM ##TempTrans" queryout "'+ @FilePath + '" -c -T'
```

The above command will use the default SQL Server instance because the '-S' argument is omitted. If the SQL Server 2016 instance is not default, specify the  `-S' argument with a value of` @@SERVERNAME`, which will include the instance name:

```
SET @SQLFile = 'bcp "SELECT x FROM ##TempTrans" queryout "'+ @FilePath + '" -c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
```